# How can I search for value in json array in mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I have json in my db (value is json type):

```
ID: 1, VALUE: ["A", "B", "C"]
ID: 2, VALUE: ["B", "C"]
ID: 2, VALUE: ["D"]
```

How can I create query to select all items where VALUE json array contains "B"?

My current query retruns empty ressult:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(value, '$') = "a";
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(value, '"B"', '$');
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=88787cec1ec5be0e5b4cfaff694b020d)**

Answer (score 0):

THE SIMPLEST WAY TO DO IT : JSON is just text, you can query it like this :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE jsonField LIKE "%B%";
```